# Unity fails to load System.Net.Http script assembly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly, telegram-bot, system.net

I'm working with **Unity 2018.2.1f1** (C# of course) and I tried to use a certain function in **Telegram.bot** library and it gave me an error indicating that it requires an **HttpClient** instance as an argument.

So I imported a System.Net.Http package **(v4.3.3)** from NuGet and put it in the assets folder; The error went away but this other annoying error poped up that says :

> *"Loading script assembly "Assets/Packages/System.Net.Http.dll" failed!".*

And the thing is that unity lets me play the game anyways and the error pretty much doesn't matter, but when I want to get a build file, it comes back and bites me in the a**. So it's pretty annoying.

- "Scripting Runtime Version" and "Api Compatibility Level" is set to
  .Net 4.x
- "Scripting Backend" is mono.
- "TargetFrameworkVersion" is v4.7.1
- I'm pairing vscode with unity for the record.

This is the script I'm trying to run:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using System.Net.Http;

public class TelegramSender : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start () {
        TelegramBotClient bot = new TelegramBotClient("<token>", new HttpClient());
        bot.SendTextMessageAsync(new ChatId(<id>), "Hello World!", ParseMode.Html);
    }

}
```

And this code actually works and sends a **"Hello World!"** to my telegram channel but the error just stays there and doesn't let you to get an apk.

By the way I don't think there is a *Web.config* or *app.config* file in a unity project or at least I can't find it.

Here's an image of the error:

[Unity Loading script assembly "System.Net.Http.dll" failed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vFqC.png)

Comment: Remove the `System.Net.Http` package you imported  from NuGet. See the duplicate on how to set it up in Unity

Comment: Thank you so much for the referral and yes it worked perfectly!!

Comment: You're welcome!